# Select columns based on another variable

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a way to select only certain columns in a table based on a certain condition. What I have is a table like:

TABLE ABCDE
col A
col B
col C
col D
col E

and a numeric variable x = 1 or 2 or 3. I need to select certain columns based on the value of x
Such that:

```
when x = 1 select A, B, D
when x = 2 select A, C, E
when x = 3 select *
```

I tried:

```
> SELECT 
> CASE  
> WHEN x = 1 THEN (SELECT A, B, D FROM TABLE ABCDE)
> WHEN x = 2 THEN (SELECT A, C, E FROM TABLE ABCDE)
> WHEN x = 3 THEN (SELECT * FROM TABLE ABCDE)
> END
```

I get:

> `ERROR: subquery must return only one column Position: 939`

I also tried referencing the table at the end:

```
> SELECT 
> CASE  
> WHEN x = 1 THEN (A, B, D )
> WHEN x = 2 THEN (A, C, E )
> WHEN x = 3 THEN (ABCDE)
> END
> FROM ABCDE
```

But I get record type instead of a table

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong, searched for other various posts, but I did not find the right answer. I am also not an expert in PostgreSQL, so I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` statement only for one field, or separately for each fields.
So, and you can not use *

For example:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN A WHEN x=2 THEN A WHEN x=3 then A END as F1, 
CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN B WHEN x=2 THEN C WHEN x=3 then B END as F2, 
CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN D WHEN x=2 THEN E WHEN x=3 then A END as F3 
FROM ABCDE
```

But if you need only this logic ->

```
when x = 1 select A, B, D
when x = 2 select A, C, E
when x = 3 select *
```

you can do it using dynamic SQL.